# view controller segue connections for multiple view controller interconnection

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Working on application that contains three view controllers A,B and C. We can navigate into any view controller from one view controller.
A->B, A->c, B->A, B->A, C->A, C->B
For this i am using storyboard segue type show for each transition. While analysis came to know the view controller old instance is not release and new instance created for each navigation. While using button event for dismissing current view controller `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` for any navigation the instance is released. But it cant be used for this case, i need to switch to any view controller and release current view controller. Could anyone suggest what segue connection used such that the release of any view controller should also be done? or any other methods to achieve that should not affect its performance. Struggling with different analysis since the retain count increase for new transition for view controllers, which is analysed from Allocation tool. Is this right to present view controllers and dismissviewocontroller completion?

Comment: If you have no restrictions on view controller navigation, it sounds like a job for a tab bar controller rather than a network of segues.

Comment: no, cant use tab.. there is some data processing on navigations

Comment: dismissViewControllerAnimated is perfect when the requirement is A->B->C and C->B->A

Comment: Yes, because A->B->C and C->B->A is what it's basically designed to do.  (You can do processing with tabs...`UITabBarControllerDelegate` gets `shouldSelectViewController:` / `didSelectViewController:` navigation messages.)

Comment: sample example for the design is three views like input , details, history.
Details view will be shown only data received from input or history like architecture. So tab cant be used here. Also i would like to use single view app not tabbed template.